# cread custom splash / launch screen using an animated svg

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add an animated SVG as an application loader in a React native app. Their docs don't offer any solution on how I could approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Back when I was working on a react native project, we had used a simple method to achieve splash screen effect.

We had called `setTimeout()` in `componentDidMount()` to navigate to the home-screen after 2 seconds. Also, we used to check whether the user is logged-in. If so, we'd navigate straight to the home screen skipping the annoying splash screen altogether.

Comment: i had this idea but this solves the visual effect of the pb ... it runs after the app has loaded ...  if nobody will give me a better solution i will choose ur answer ... but u know it as well as i know it that it is a trick rather than a 100% solution to ease the wait :)